# iTextSharp watermark not appearing on a scanned PDF

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation

I have some code used to watermark PDFs using iTextSharp.  The code works fine for most PDFs, but there has been one test case where the watermark is not visible on a PDF of a scanned document.  (I have other scanned documents where it does appear though).

I am using the `GetOverContent()` method.

This is my code for adding the watermark;

```
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(this.inputFilename))
{
    // Set transparent  - 1
    PdfGState gstate = new PdfGState();
    gstate.FillOpacity = 0.4f;
    gstate.StrokeOpacity = 0.5f;
    // 2
    BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, Encoding.ASCII.EncodingName, false);

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream);

        // Must start at 1 because 0 is not an actual page.
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            Rectangle pageSize = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i);

            // Gets the content ABOVE the PDF, Another option is GetUnderContent(...)  
            // which will place the text below the PDF content. 
            PdfContentByte pdfPageContents = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(i);
            pdfPageContents.BeginText(); // Start working with text.

            // 1 
            pdfPageContents.SaveState();
            pdfPageContents.SetGState(gstate);

            float hypotenuse = (float)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(pageSize.Width, 2) + Math.Pow(pageSize.Height, 2));
            float glyphWidth = baseFont.GetWidth("My watermark text");
            float fontSize = 1000 * (hypotenuse * 0.8f) / glyphWidth;
            float angle = (float)(Math.Atan(pageSize.Height / pageSize.Width) * (180 / Math.PI));

            // Create a font to work with 
            pdfPageContents.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, fontSize);
            pdfPageContents.SetRGBColorFill(128, 128, 128); // Sets the color of the font, GRAY in this instance

            // Note: The x,y of the Pdf Matrix is from bottom left corner. 
            // This command tells iTextSharp to write the text at a certain location with a certain angle.
            // Again, this will angle the text from bottom left corner to top right corner and it will 
            // place the text in the middle of the page. 
            pdfPageContents.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "My watermark text", pageSize.Width / 2, pageSize.Height / 2, angle);
            pdfPageContents.EndText(); // Done working with text
            pdfPageContents.RestoreState();
        }

        pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true; // enable this if you want the PDF flattened. 
        pdfStamper.FreeTextFlattening = true; // enable this if you want the PDF flattened. 
        pdfStamper.Close(); // Always close the stamper or you'll have a 0 byte stream. 

        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why the watermark may not be appearing and what I can try to fix it?

Kind regards.

Comment: Please share the example for which the code fails.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't because the only example PDF contains confidential information.

Comment: Well, at first glance an error in the code is even documented, "The x,y of the Pdf Matrix is from bottom left corner" - This is not always true, the origin of the coordinates can be literally anywhere (within reasonable ranges), it merely *often* is in the lower left. Thus, take the lower left coordinates of the `Rectangle pageSize` into consideration, too. If that doesn't solve the issue, I have no idea without the sample document.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I will do some further investigation to check that out.

Comment: Thanks mkl you were absolutely spot on!  I had assumed that the bottom left of the page would have co-ordinates of (0,0) but for this document the co-ordinates were (0, 7022).  I wasn't factoring in the LEFT and BOTTOM starting values when positioning my text.  Thank you very much for the tip! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is based on an assumption it even documents as a fact:

```
// Note: The x,y of the Pdf Matrix is from bottom left corner. 
// This command tells iTextSharp to write the text at a certain location with a certain angle.
// Again, this will angle the text from bottom left corner to top right corner and it will 
// place the text in the middle of the page. 
pdfPageContents.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "My watermark text", pageSize.Width / 2, pageSize.Height / 2, angle);
```

The assumption that *the x,y of the Pdf Matrix is from bottom left corner* unfortunately is wrong: While it indeed is very often the case that the origin of the PDF coordinate system (the default user space coordinate system, to be more precise) is in the lower left corner of the page, this is *not required*, the origin actually can be literally anywhere (within reasonable limits).

Thus, one has to take the lower left coordinates of the `Rectangle pageSize` into consideration, too.

The OP meanwhile has confirmed:

> I had assumed that the bottom left of the page would have co-ordinates of (0,0) but for this document the co-ordinates were (0, 7022).